# High availability solution for NodeJS, Nginx and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, high-availability, pm2

I need opinion and best practice from someone more experienced in configuring nginx+nodejs+mongodb.

I'm working on custom build cloud application based on MongoDB and NodeJS. As reverse proxy server I'm using nginx, and for manage NodeJS I'm using PM2. At this moment I have separate servers, one for MongoDB database and one for serving API application (Nginx + NodeJS). For now I'm using PM2 and I set up that API is running as cluster on 1-core VPS.

In future I will need to configure high availability solution. Regarding database I don't use any replication or clustering yet. I see lots of potential things to optimize in future and I believe that achieving HA is not to hard to achieve with this technologies but can someone say his opinion and what I should take care first? I don't have to much experience in configuring HA so every advice is good advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> "I believe that achieving HA is not to hard ... I don't have to much experience in configuring HA"

There's an old saying that you should **never say that don't have experience in something but you don't think it's difficult**. How difficult it is you will find out in the worst possible time.

If you don't know how to do it then no one will answer it on Stack Overflow because it takes years to get the required experience. You would be better off by using working solutions instead of reinventing your own. For Mongo you can use [Compose](https://www.compose.com/) or [mLab](https://mlab.com/). For Node you can use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html). For static assets use [MaxCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/) or [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). There are much more services to choose from.

Of course if you can do it yourself better then Compose and Heroku then by all means go ahead and do it. But if you don't then you will save yourself a lot of trouble if you go with a working solution.

Another plus is that both Heroku and mLab gives you free plans to start developing right away without paying anything but as soon as your application gains some traction you are in a good place to start scaling it massively if you have to.

Even if you decide to roll your own solution then you should still read the documentation of all of those and similar services because they nicely explain the functionality that you will have o implement and the problems that you are going to face.

Comment: I see your point, and I'm aware of troubles we could experience with custom architecture but this is what we have. I didn't mean to say that this all is easy to achieve but I think we are using solid and promising technologies with ability to be easily scalable. I don't expect that someone will tell me everything but just looking for directions and best practices, nothing else.